# To distinguish between device and server internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, sharepoint

I am trying to hit a sharepoint server from my phone (iOS) having wifi feature. Basically, I am making an ajax call to the Sharepoint server and using the response to do further tasks. When my device has wifi off, I get the `http response status` as '0' and similarly when the device has wifi 'on', but Sharepoint server is not connectible, then also status comes as '0'.

How can I differentiate between the two scenarios and handle both the scenarios differently?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

ARC version:
https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability